# Window close only work "on Click"

Tags: javascript

EDIT:

I solved myself like this:

```
 function closeWin() {
     myWindow = window.open("", "page");
     myWindow.close();
 }
```

I've got this code

custom.js

```
var myWindow;
function openWin() {
   myWindow = window.open("page.php", "page");
}

function closeWin() {
   myWindow.close();
}
```

I open the window like this in index

```
<a onClick = "openWin()"></a>
```

And I want it to close itself in logout without clicking any link or button like this:

```
closeWin();
```

It doesn't work!
Any solution?

Comment: Please provide a more complete explanation of what you are doing and what do you expect. You'd better post the complete HTML/Javascript code where these functions are being called from.

Comment: And what is this "logout" you say? Is it an hiperlink within `page.php`? Is it simply closing the opened page?

Comment: No, it also destroy a session so I need it to be a different page.

Answer (score 2):

Your `myWindow` reference is only in the scope of the `openWin()` function, so when you call `closeWin()`, `myWindow` variable there is simply of type `undefined`. You need to create a global variable `myWindow` or pass it as an argument to the `closeWin` function, for example:

```
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("page.php", "page");
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
```

or

```
function closeWin(myWindow) {
    myWindow.close();
}
```

Also note that `myWindow` can be closed without having the reference saved. You can simply call `window.close()` in the `closeWin` function.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I edited the question, please give a look!

Comment: how about simple `window.close()`?

Comment: where do you call `closeWin()` function from?

Comment: you can't call `closeWin()` function from `custom.js` file in `logout.php`. it simply doesn't exist in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100358/discussion-between-demetriomontalto-and-nhor).